# how do i add a dom in js to hide first page and display the second page?when i try to add dom in the JS i am not able to block the content form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not able to add DOM to the JS when i try to hide my first page and add a second page after submit button.I have used function click me and placed the element ID by buttonclick.innerhtml

Please help me a method to hide my first page and display the second page for the in the JS after click my Submit button

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not how you do it! First of all, you don't create a DOM by using `innerHTML` which is slow and poses a security risk. If you click on a submit button, the page will be redirected. You just need to prevent the default behavior which you can find plenty of guides here on SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.